# Comparing and Updating 2 Different Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to compare 1 worksheet (Sheet1) to another similar worksheet (Sheet2)

Sheet2 contains up to date information,which needs to be transferred to Sheet1.

However, I've run into a couple of problems:

1. There are some rows in Sheet1 that are not Sheet2. These need to be ignored/skipped over
2. There are some rows in Sheet2 that are not Sheet1. These need to be appended to the end of Sheet1
3. If a row exists in both Sheets, the information from the row sheet 2 needs to be transferred to the corresponding row in Sheet1

For what its worth, they have same number of columns and the column titles are exactly the same.

I've tried using a dictionary object to accomplish this but am still having all sorts of trouble.

Here's the code I have tried thus far:

```
Sub createDictionary()
    Dim dict1, dict2 As Object
    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim maxRows1, maxRows2 As Long
    Dim i, ii, j, k As Integer

    maxRows1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To maxRows1

      Dim cell1 As String

      cell1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i, 2).Text & " " & Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i, 11).Text

        If Not dict1.Exists(cell1) Then
            dict1.Add cell1, cell1
        End If

    Next i

    maxRows2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    For ii = 2 To maxRows2

        Dim cell2 As String

        cell2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(ii, 11).Text

        If Not dict2.Exists(cell2) Then
            dict2.Add cell2, cell2
        End If

    Next ii

    Dim rngSearch1, rngFound1, rngSearch2, rngFound2 As Range

    For j = 2 To maxRows1

    Dim Sheet1Str, Sheet2Str As String
    Sheet1Str = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, 2).Text & " " & Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, 11).Text
    Sheet2Str = Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(j, 11).Text


        If dict2.Exists(Sheet1Str) = False Then


        'ElseIf Not dict1.Exists(Sheet2) Then
        '
        '    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j & ":" & "Z" & j).Copy
        '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & maxRows1 + 1).Insert
        '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & maxRows1 + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U" & maxRows1 + 1) = "INCH"
        '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q" & maxRows1 + 1) = "FPM"
        '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S" & maxRows1 + 1) = "INCHES WIDE"

        '    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & j) = Replace(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & j), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & j), "")
        '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & maxRows1 + 1) = Trim(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & j))

        Else
            For k = 3 To 6
            If Not k = 11 Then
                    If Not UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, k).Value) = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(j, k).Value) Then
                         Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, k).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(j, k).Value
                    End If
            End If
            Next k

        End If

    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Does row order on `Sheet1` matter, or could the solution change their order?

Comment: Let's assume for now that row order does not matter.

Comment: You are repeating the same question in multiple threads, which is a very bad idea because you have a duplication of effort from people that are trying to help you. On 8/1 you posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082412/update-worksheet-by-comparing-it-to-another-worksheet   then on 8/5 you posted 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127573/comparing-two-worksheets-and-updating  and now you have posted this THIRD VERSION!! Pick a thread and STICK WITH IT until RESOLVED!!

Answer (score 0):

Cool question, and the "does row order matter" question above lends itself nicely to using Excel's built in `Range.RemoveDuplicates` method. Let's get into it...

Suppose `Sheet1` looks like this:

[image: sheet_1_start]

Let's say `Sheet2` looks like this:

[image: sheet_2_start]

All the conditions that are described in your original question are met here. Namely:

1. There are rows on `Sheet1` that are not on `Sheet2` (row 2, for example). These will be left alone.
2. There are rows on `Sheet2` that are not on `Sheet1` (row 2, for example). These will be added to `Sheet1`.
3. There are rows that are the same on `Sheet2` and `Sheet1`, save for a single update. (Row 7 on `Sheet2`, for example.) These rows will be updated on `Sheet1`. Of course, your situation will be different -- perhaps more columns might be updated, or they might not be in column E like my example -- you'll need to do a bit of customization here.

The following heavily-commented script walks through copying data from `Sheet2` to `Sheet1`, then letting Excel's built-in `Range.RemoveDuplicates` method kill all of the rows that have been updated in column E. The script also makes use of a couple handy functions: `LastRowNum` and `LastColNum`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeSheetTwoIntoSheetOne()

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, _
    LastCol As Long

'setup - set references up-front
LastRow2 = LastRowNum(Sheet2)
LastRow1 = LastRowNum(Sheet1)
LastCol = LastColNum(Sheet1) '<~ last col the same on both sheets

'setup - identify the data block on sheet 2
With Sheet2
    Set Range2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow2, LastCol))
End With

'setup - identify the data block on sheet 1
With Sheet1
    Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow1, LastCol))
End With

'step 1 - move the data block on sheet 1 down the sheet
'         to allow room for the data block from sheet 2
Range1.Cut Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1)

'step 2 - move the data block from sheet 2 into the recently-
'         cleared space on sheet 1
Range2.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(2, 1)

'step 3 - find the NEW last row on sheet 1
LastRow1 = LastRowNum(Sheet1)

'step 4 - use excel's built-in duplicate removal to
'         kill all dupes on every column EXCEPT for those
'         that might have been updated on sheet 2...
'         in this example, Column E is where updates take place
With Sheet1
    Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow1, LastCol))
    Range1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub

'this handy function allows us to find the last row with a one-liner
Public Function LastRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRowNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        LastRowNum = 1
    End If
End Function

'this handy function allows us to find the last column with a one-liner
Public Function LastColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastColNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        LastColNum = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Running this script results in the following:

[image: end]